# Navigation bar going under status bar in iOS 9

Tags: ios

How do I prevent the navigation bar from going under the status bar in ios 9?

[image]

Comment: Hi ,Amol, It is the same behaviour everybuddy gets. As it is the default behaviour. You can not change it. For iOS 8, and 9 i guess.

Comment: You can try not to use NAvigation bar, and put a view there.

Comment: We should not put -1 to a guy, who is just arrived to ask question. We need to encourage him.

Comment: Check this, you can see the small video like, https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/ and read the third point.

Answer (score -1):

try this it is working in my case :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Will it not hide the Status bar? @Amol wants it to show status bar, and NAvigation bar both, But wants not to  go navigation bar behind status bar.

Comment: This is not the answer to actual question.